# Unity: How To Serialize A Class Inside Struct

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, struct

```
public class TopClass
{
    [System.Serializable] 
    public struct WantToBeVisibleInInspector
    {
        public SomeEnum appearsInInspector; 
        public SomeClass doesNOTAppearInInspector; 
    } 
    [SerializeField] private WantToBeVisibleInInspector[] meWant;
}
```

SomeEnum shows on the inspector but the SomeClass does not.
Why does this occur and how to fix it?

Comment: Because SomeClass does not have System.Serializable attribute.

Comment: @shingo is right. You most probably are missing the ```[Serializable]``` keyword right in your ```SomeClass``` script/definition